# Java JTextArea update

Tags: java, jtextarea

Currently my JTextArea just updates itself when the loop is finished, for example

Loop for i = 1, do nothing 
Loop for i = 2, do nothing

When the loop is finished then it actually displays the next text

```
    for(Integer i = 0; i<Integer.parseInt(this.number.getText()); i++) {

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String request = read.readLine();

        System.out.println("aaa");

        if (!request.equals("</Success>")) {

            int status = this.generateErrorLogs(request);
        }
    }
```

So when the for loop is finished for each i the text is added for example "Error"

For loop i = 1, write to area
For loop i = 2, write to area

Im currently updating the text area like this

```
public int generateErrorLogs(String request) {

        Update status = new Update(this.area);

        switch (request) {

            case "<Error>LinkWebAccountDialog.shortError</Error>":
                status.updateArea("Password too short");
                return 0;
            case "<Error>Error.emailAlreadyUsed</Error>":
                this.area.append("Email already used\n");
                return 1;
            default:
                return 2;
        }
    }
```

And

```
public class Update {

    private JTextArea area;

    public Update(JTextArea area) {

        this.area = area;
    }

    public void updateArea(final String text) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                updateTextArea(text);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateTextArea(String text) {

        this.area.append(text + "\n");
    }
}
```

The question is how do I make the loop it updates the textArea text each time i changes isntead of wait for the loop to finish

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?

Comment: Please ask a question

Comment: Done. sorry. Didnt notice

Comment: I don't understand how the pieces of code are connected. Can't you call your update from inside the loop?